# How to passing props id into methods in vue js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

My project are using laravel as backend and vue as front end.
I want to passing props id into methods.
Then when i clicked button it will get the users id and running the continues process.

in my view i using this to passing id to vue components.

```
<conversation_send_message_form user_id="{{ $user->id }}"></conversation_send_message_form>
```

After that this is my vue code

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            body: null,
            recipients: [],
        }
    },
    props: ['id'],
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'sendMessage'
        ]),
        send(){
            this.sendMessage({
                recipientIds: this.id,
                body: this.body
            }).then(() =>{
                this.recipients= []
                this.body = null
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here will receive the data and process it

```
sendMessage ({dispatch, commit}, {body, recipientIds}) {
    return api.storeMessage({
        body: body,
        recipientIds: recipientIds
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
},
```

My Api

```
storeMessage({body, recipientIds}){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post('/webapi/conversations', {
            body: body,
            recipients: recipientIds
        }).then((response) =>{
            resolve(response)
        })
    })
},
```

In my scenario i need a new methods to get the props id and passing into the new methods "Send", inside it will passing the id into recipientIds, then the api will handle for it. But i had no idea how to get the props id. Anyone can help me?

Comment: you can access data inside methods using 'this'. So for example, this.id would be the data stored in the id prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to passing data to your vue components, one is to use a static prop

```
<conversation_send_message_form user_id="15"></conversation_send_message_form>
```

and the other is to use dynamic properties

```
<conversation_send_message_form v-bind:user_id="user.id"></conversation_send_message_form>
```

> Be aware of laravel blade vs mustache-like syntax

those properties are being received in component with "props", and accesible inside js with this.PROPNAME (and accesible inside template with PROPNAME directly) So your only problem is name mismatch, just change

```
export default {
    props: ['userId'],
    send() {
            this.sendMessage({
                recipientIds: this.userId,
                body: this.body
            }).then(() =>{
                this.recipients= []
                this.body = null
            })
     },
}
```

Be also aware of naming with camelCase vs kebab-case: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case